# How to access Interactive Generator block (IG) in Vector CANoe CAPL?

Tags: can-bus, capl

I want to access IG block in CAPL,e.g activate/deactivate message sending, set signal value. but I didn't find this kind of capl function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare you're own message in CAPL, then you should use function "output" to send it on CAN. Below example send message with ID 0x100 with 100ms cycle.

```
enter code here
variables
{
  msTimer timer200ms;
  msTimer timer100ms;
  message 0x100 msg = {
    DLC = 8, 
    byte(0) = 0x00, byte(1) = 0x00, byte(2) = 0x00, byte(3) = 0x00,
    byte(4) = 0x00, byte(5) = 0x00, byte(6) = 0x00, byte(7) = 0x00 
 };
  byte myByte[8];
}

on timer timer200ms{
  int i=0, j=0;

  if(i<7){
    if(j<256){
      myByte[i] = j;
      write("frame %d have been change for %d", i, j);
      j++;
      if(j==255){
        i++;
        j=0;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
   cancelTimer(timer200ms); 
  }
}

on timer timer100ms{
    msg.byte(0) = myByte[0];
    msg.byte(1) = myByte[1];
    msg.byte(2) = myByte[2];
    msg.byte(3) = myByte[3];
    msg.byte(4) = myByte[4];
    msg.byte(5) = myByte[5];
    msg.byte(6) = myByte[6];
    msg.byte(7) = myByte[7];
    output(msg);
}

on start{
  setTimerCyclic(timer100ms, 100);
  setTimerCyclic(timer200ms, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some function on key press or , functions connected to a Panel , the IG is just an easyer way to send messages but you cannot connect the capl with IG because are diferent nodes .